# How do I create a new list with information calculated from other information in my json?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode12

#here is my view model#

```
import Foundation

class CategoriesModel:ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var restaurantList = [Categories]()
    
    init() {
        //get path to json data
        let pathString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "json")
        
        if let path = pathString {
            
            // create url object
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            
            do {
                //create data object with data at url
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                
                do {
                    let restaurantData = try decoder.decode([Categories].self, from: data)
                    
                    self.restaurantList = restaurantData
                    //restaurantList.shuffle()
                
                }
                catch {
                    //error decoding json
                    print(error)
                }
                
            }
            catch {
                //error fetching url
                print(error)
            }
            
            
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

#here is my model#

```
import Foundation

struct Categories: Identifiable, Decodable {
    
    var id = 0
    var name:String = ""
    var truckOrRestaurant = ""
    var type:[String] = [String]()
    var pic:String = ""
    var price:String = ""
    var hours:[String:[String]] = [String:[String]]()
    var hoursString:String = ""
    var stars:String = ""
    var website:String = ""
    var location:String = ""
    var coordinates:[Double] = [Double]()
    var phoneNumber:String = ""
    var currency:String = ""
    var review:String = ""
    var wait:String = ""
    
}
```

#some of one of my views#

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct DiscoverTab: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var restaurantInfo:CategoriesModel
    @StateObject private var location = LocationCode()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Sort by:")
                Button(action:{
                    //sort alphabetically
                    //restaurantInfo.restaurantList.sort()
                }, label:{
                    Text("Alphabetical")
                        .background(Color.yellow)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                        
                })
                Button(action:{
                    //sort alphabetically
                    //restaurantInfo.restaurantList.sort()
                }, label:{
                    Text("Distance")
                        .background(Color.yellow)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                })
...
```

I believe I have to use some sort of different properties in the model, but how do I sort alphabetically, (.sort() doesn't work), and by different pieces of information found in my json. Also, how would I sort data that doesn't come from my json? I have a different function in my viewmodel that returns "open" if a restaurant is open at any given time or "closed" vice versa. Whenever I try to create a new published list in my viewmodel and append the restaurant name to it, I get an error. Is there some extra protocol I need to use or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way is to sort the data in the view model.

First of all name the model in singular form `Category`, one instance is one category

```
struct Category: Identifiable, Decodable {
```

in `CategoriesModel` add a method to sort the array by key paths

```
func sort<T : Comparable>(keyPath: KeyPath<Category,T>) {
    restaurantList.sort { c1, c2 in
        c1[keyPath: keyPath] < c2[keyPath: keyPath]
    }
}
```

Then, in the button action call the custom sort method

```
Button(action:{
    //sort alphabetically
    restaurantInfo.restaurantList.sort(keyPath: \.name)
}
```

For the distance you have to add the logic also in the view model

Comment: How would I sort data that doesn't come from my json? I have a different function in my viewmodel that returns "open" if a restaurant is open at any given time or "closed" vice versa. Whenever I try to create a new published list in my viewmodel and append the restaurant name to it, I get an error. Is there some extra protocol I need to use or something?

Comment: This is another question and requires more information.

Comment: Thank you, I have no doubt this is the correct answer, I'm just a beginner programmer and I'm still figuring out this solution.