# How do I add multiple static funcs to compare my json data multiple ways in my model using Comparable?

Tags: swift, xcode, comparable, xcode12

```
struct Categories:Identifiable, Decodable, Hashable, Comparable {
    
    static func < (lhs: Categories, rhs: Categories) -> Bool {
        
        lhs.name<rhs.name
        
    }
    
    static func < (lhs: Categories, rhs: Categories) -> Bool {
        
        lhs.cost<rhs.cost
        
    }
    
    
    var id = UUID()
    var name:String = ""
    var cost:String = ""
    var pic:String = ""
    var description:String = ""
    var reviews:String = ""
    var stars:String = ""
    var phoneNumber:String = ""
    var type:String = ""
    
    
    
}
```

This gives me an error obviously, I was wondering how I could have multiple functions for multiple ways of sorting my json data so I can sort my data different ways at a press of a button

Comment: Why the sort logic should be put in `Categories`? Why not keeping the sort depending on the "button" logic, there and not here on `Categories`?

Comment: You can use `static func nameSorted(_ category1: Categories, _ category2: Categories) -> Bool { return category1.name < category2.name }`, and then `categories.sorted(by: Categories.nameSorted(_:_:))` to use, for instance...

Comment: As I suggested in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69623980/how-do-i-create-a-new-list-with-information-calculated-from-other-information-in) use key paths.